# How do I set up RAID0 using extra two drives?

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid0

I have been looking around for a suitable tutorial to help me set up a [RAID0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0) across two (or more) drives, but not moving the actual installation of Linux Mint onto that RAID setup.

A coworker had pointed me to [this tutorial](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/setting-up-raid-on-existing/), and I could not make heads, nor tails of it.

Comment: The tutorial looks pretty clear (you actually only need steps 1 and 2). Which parts are you having trouble understanding or doing?

Comment: @jordanm I think my biggest thing is that the author uses hard values for his devices instead of references. I'm not sure how I would modify the given commands to point to my specific drives instead of his example drives, and change it to raid0 instead of raid1.

Comment: The `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` are the partitions, replace those. `--level=1` is what specifies the level. Note that he is creating two RAID1 volumes. See `man mdadm` for the full documentation.

Comment: @jordanm nevermind. that was exactly what I needed to give it a spin. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, let it be clear that all your data will be destroyed on both of the array members (drives), so back it up first!

Open terminal and become [`root`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like) ([`su`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix))); if you have [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) enabled, you may also do for example `sudo -i`; see [`man sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) for all options):

```
sudo -i
```

Install *necessary* and *optional* software needed.

Prerequisites, these are *necessary*:

- [`mdadm`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm)
- [`gdisk`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/gdisk) / ([`fdisk`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk))

Optional software *to fully correspond with this answer, you may do without them*:

- [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)
- [`wipefs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/wipefs)
- [`iotop`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop)
- [`gparted`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/gparted)

I recommend installing all of it:

```
apt-get install mdadm gdisk pv util-linux iotop gparted
```

First, we should erase the drives, if there was any data and filesystems before, that is. Suppose we have 2 members: `sda` and `sdb`.

```
pv < /dev/zero > /dev/sda
pv < /dev/zero > /dev/sdb
```

Alternately, if you are running each command with `sudo`, this part would look like this:

```
sudo bash -c 'pv < /dev/zero > /dev/sda'
sudo bash -c 'pv < /dev/zero > /dev/sdb'
```

To double-check if there is nothing left behind, you may peek with GParted on both of the drives, and if there is any filesystem other than `unknown`, wipe it:

```
wipefs -a /dev/sda
wipefs -a /dev/sdb
```

[You should partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/320103/126755) the drives, depending on, whether you want [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) or [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table):

```
fdisk /dev/sdX
```

or

```
gdisk /dev/sdX
```

Supposing you would use the new standard, [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) that is.

We initialize both of the drives with GUID partition table ([GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)):

```
gdisk /dev/sda
gdisk /dev/sdb
```

In both cases use the following:

`o` <kbd>Enter</kbd> for new empty GUID partition table ([GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table))
`y` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm your decision
`w` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write changes
`y` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm your decision

Don't do this with GParted, because it would create a filesystem in the process, which we don't want, use `gdisk` again:

```
gdisk /dev/sda
gdisk /dev/sdb
```

In both cases use the following:
`n` <kbd>Enter</kbd> for new partition
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for first partition
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for default of the first sector
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for default of the last sector
`fd00` <kbd>Enter</kbd> for Linux RAID type
`w` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write changes
`y` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm your decision

To triple-check if there is nothing left behind, you may peek with GParted on both of the newly created partitions, and if they contain any filesystem other than `unknown`, wipe it:

```
wipefs -a /dev/sda1
wipefs -a /dev/sdb1
```

You can examine the drives now:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

It should say in parentheses `(type ee)` now.

If it does, we now examine the partitions:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

It should say `No md superblock detected` now.

If it does, we can create the RAID0 array:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

We shall wait until the array is fully created, this process we may watch with:

```
watch -n 1 cat /proc/mdstat
```

After creation of the array, we should look at its detail:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

It should say `Active devices: 2`, `Working devices: 2` and that `State: clean`.

Now we create filesystem on the array, if you use `ext4`, this is better to be avoided, because of `ext4lazyinit` would take noticeable amount of time, hence the name, "lazyinit":

> ```
> mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
> ```

Instead, you should force a full instant initialization with:

```
mkfs.ext4 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0 /dev/md0
```

By specifying these options, the inodes and the journal will be initialized immediately during creation.

If you chose to take a shortcut and created the `ext4` filesystem with the "better avoided command", note that `ext4lazyinit` will take noticeable amount of time to initialize all of the inodes, you may watch it until it is done, e.g. with:

```
iotop
```

Either way you choose to make the file system initialization, you should mount it after it has done its initialization:

We now create some directory for this RAID0 array:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/raid0
```

And simply mount it:

```
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raid0
```

Since we are essentially done, we may use GParted again to quickly check if it shows `linux-raid` filesystem, together with the `raid` flag on both of the drives.

If it does, we properly created the RAID0 array with [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitions and can now copy files on it.

Now we need to edit `fstab`, with your favorite text editor:

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

And add add an entry to it:

```
/dev/md0                /mnt/raid0              ext4    defaults        0 0
```

You may check if it is correct, after you save the changes:

```
mount -av | grep raid0
```

It should say `already mounted`.

If it does, we save the array configuration:

```
mdadm --detail --scan --verbose >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Check if you did everything according to plan, and if so, you may restart:

```
reboot
```

Comment: you could add commands for gparted if you're mentioning them. Otherwise works perfectly fine.