# Confused with results after dd operation on RAID6 configuration

Tags: filesystems, dd, software-raid

I am working with the RAID6 configuration with 4 disks involved, each of size 8TB. Hence the total capacity = (n-2) * s, where `n` = number of disks and `s` = size of disks. So in my case it is 16TB.

Below is the information before the `dd` operation is performed:

```
df -h /mnt/raid6/

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0         15T  1.1G   14T   1% /mnt/raid6
```

`dd` operation performed:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/md0 bs=1G count=5 oflag=dsync

5+0 records in
5+0 records out
5368709120 bytes (5.4 GB) copied, 76.7451 s, 70.0 MB/s
```

Information after performing dd operation:

```
df -h /mnt/raid6/

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0         64Z   64Z   15T 100% /mnt/raid6
```

My confusion is here, when I have performed a write operation with 5GB file on the RAID6 devices, why the output is shown as **Used = 64Z**?

Comment: Did you do that `dd` while `/mnt/raid6` was mounted?

Comment: You corrupted your filesystem.

Comment: @AlexP : yes, the operation was performed after mounting, /mnt/raid6.

Comment: Your file system is corrupt. You need to `mkfs` again. I hope you did not have any data there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is completely erasing all file system metadata, thus irrevocably making it unusable.

You have to [do the partitioning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320103/whats-the-difference-between-creating-mdadm-array-using-partitions-or-the-whole) again or better to re-create the array [according to this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320330/126755).

If you want to check the filesystem on the array is doing fine, just create a file on the mounted array e.g.:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/raid6/testfile bs=1M count=8192
```

Comment: thanks for response, the reason for doing dd operation is to check the read/write operation on that disk/raid after creation of RAID. Is that the right way to do or any other proper way to check read/write operations after RAID creation.